# Applications of distance correlation

Tags: correlation, statistical-finance, dependence

This [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/848/time-series-similarity-measures) mentions [distance correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation).

Where has this concept been applied to financial data and provided new insight? 
Do you know any examples or references?